# MySQL error: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to load data into an existing table using this command:
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/clothes.txt' INTO TABLE closet;

but keep getting the error: ERROR 2068 (HY000): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.

I tried multiple things to fix it, including but not kimited to:

1. Setting the global variables using this command: SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;
2. Adding this to my connection: OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1
3. Running the command without the 'LOCAL' word
4. Changing my forward slashes to back slashes in the path
5. Changing my global variable local_infile to be on
   and others.

Nothing seems to solve the problem.
I would appreciate any help!

Thank you so much.

Comment: Set the `secure_file_priv` system variable to the path of  your file. Note: if you set it to an empty string of "",no path restriction is imposed.

Comment: Thank you! I get a comment saying that this variable is for read only... what can I do about that?

Comment: You can edit the option file in the OS, e.g the default path in linux is /etc/my.cnf, add the  variable with its value defined under `mysqld` section. Then restart mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

When Log in MySQL using command prompt, type this:

```
mysql -u YourUsername -pYourPassword --local_infile=1
```

Then:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/clothes.txt' INTO TABLE closet;
```